# Find the sum $\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\dots+\frac{1}{99\cdot 100}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please help me calculate the following sum

> $$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\dots+\frac{1}{99\cdot 100}$$

Answer (score 18):

HINT: $\dfrac1{n(n+1)}=\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n+1}$

Comment: This is the only answer so far that didn't outright solve the homework problem...

Comment: @ Ha Hi: Complete answer.

Comment: For most homework problems, I think a hint is much more appropriate than a complete solution. Our job in these situations is not to do the students' work for them. But, I've been guilty of doing just that. So, I guess we just need to restrain ourselves a bit.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\dots+\frac{1}{99\cdot 100}\\=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{100}\\=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{100}=\frac{49}{100}=0.49$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} =\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}=\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\frac{1}{99 \cdot 100}= \frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{100}$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{99 \cdot 100}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+ \ldots-\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{100}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{100}=\frac{49}{100}.$$

general case:

$$\frac{1}{n \cdot (n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: why (-1) downvoter?

Comment: I didn’t do it, so I’m guessing, but probably because you solved a homework problem completely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Are you kidding ? I don't know one like this :)

Comment: Perhaps because your answer is a duplicate of the other two.

Comment: Really ? I don't care but I think is not ok how many vote.